# How to get current offset in Kafka 0.10.x without shell?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any way to get the current offset in Kafka 0.10.x? I do not want to use shell commands.

When I use the API's `consumer.endOffsets(...)`, I can get the last offsets (logSize). However `consumer.position(...)` does not get me the current offset!

All in all, I want to get the current offset, log size and lag in one partition.

Comment: No out-of-box APIs are offered. A possible way is to write your methods based on ConsumerGroupCommand code.

Comment: kafka tool will give you current offset. http://www.kafkatool.com/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `KafkaConsumer#committed()` to get the latest committed position. Thus, I you disable auto-commit and do manual commits, you can compute the exact lag each time you do a commit.

On the other hand, each record you do process, provide its offset via `ConsumerRecord#offset()`, thus, you can also compute the lag after reading a single record (for the record's partition).

Comment: KafkaConsumer#committed() in 0.10.x likes OffsetFetchRequest in 0.8.x,I found OffsetFetchRequest also can get what I want. And if I want to know commit time, there is only way to get it by using  ConsumerRecord#timestamp()?

Comment: `ConsumerRecord#timestamp()` return the record embedded timestamp that is not related to commit time. Either, a producer can set this timestamp value arbitrarily; or. if it is not set, and broker append-time policy is enabled, the broker will set the timestamp on write. Thus, it is a *write* timestamp and not related to consumer commits.

Comment: How I can get offset's commit time? I want to konw last commit time for each partition,what structure of group,topic and offset on brokers? In 0.8.x I can get zookeeper node structure for them.However I can not find any thing about commit to kafka brokers.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to get commit time. It should be possible though to read the Kafka topic `__consumer_offsets` and extract the commit timestamps from there -- but I am not sure -- and it would be tricky.

Comment: Do you konw any documents or articles about commit to kafka brokers instead of commit to zookeeper.There are some introduction in official documents but no details.

Comment: No. But you might want to start a different question for this... I think I did answer your original question.